# Remove a net.msmq binding from IIS using Powershell

Tags: iis, powershell, iis-7.5, msmq

Automating some IIS stuff with Powershell. I needed to add an net.msmq binding using the approach listed here:
[Why Powershell's New-WebBinding commandlet creates incorrect HostHeader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9424362/why-powershells-new-webbinding-commandlet-creates-incorrect-hostheader)

Where I add using something like

```
New-ItemProperty -Path 'IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site' -Name Bindings -value @{protocol="net.msmq"; bindingInformation="server.domain.com"}
```

So now I need to automate removal of that binding (say the queue server changes).  I have messed around with all the Collection cmdlets, and I cannot figure out a way to remove an item.

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path 'IIS\Sites\Default Web Site' -Name bindings
```

will return a collection.  I can iterate through with ForEach, but I cannot seem to find the magic command to remove an item once I find it.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
$prop = (get-ItemProperty -Path 'IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site' -Name bindings).Collection | ? {$_.Protocol -ne "net.msmq"}
Set-ItemProperty "IIS:\sites\Default Web Site" -name bindings -value $prop
```

Comment: I knew it was something simple I just wasn't putting together.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Remove-ItemProperty 'IIS:\Sites\DemoSite' -Name bindings -AtElement @{protocol="http";bindingInformation="*:80:DemoSite2"}

straight off the technet......