# How to interpret BindingInformation configured with powershell

Tags: iis, powershell

Im autodeploying an old website which have this binding:

```
net.tcp 808:*
```

But when I use WebAdministration to set it like this:

```
New-WebBinding -Name "site" -Procotol "net.tcp" -Port 808
```

I get this binding:

```
net.tcp *:808:
```

Are they the same?

Comment: Nevermind, I can use: New-ItemProperty -Path "IIS:\sites\sitename" -Name Bindings -value @{protocol="net.tcp"; bindingInformation="808:*"} to achieve the same. Thx to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9424362/why-powershells-new-webbinding-commandlet-creates-incorrect-hostheader

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nevermind, I can use:

```
New-ItemProperty -Path "IIS:\sites\sitename" -Name Bindings -value @{protocol="net.tcp"; bindingInformation="808:*"}
```

to achieve the same.

Thx to: [Why Powershell's New-WebBinding commandlet creates incorrect HostHeader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9424362/why-powershells-new-webbinding-commandlet-creates-incorrect-hostheader)