# (IIS) Adding net.tcp binding to a website using Powershell

Tags: powershell, iis, binding, iis-7, iis-7.5

I have a IIS 8 server I'm trying to replicate.

Get-Website

under "Bindings" I have a certain website with the following binding:

```
net.tcp 6202:*
```

How can I set this binding using Powershell on the replica?

I tried this:

```
Set-ItemProperty IIS:\Sites\SITENAME -Name bindings -Value 'net.tcp 6202:*' -Force
```

But it appears to simply does not do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following, based on another [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20002614/702944)

```
Set-ItemProperty IIS:\Sites\SITENAME -Name bindings -Value @{protocol="net.tcp"; bindingInformation="6202:*"} -Force
```

Comment: Cool!
I'd have never guessed it.
Do you know how would I be able to tell such thing next time?

Comment: I don't have IIS so I can test it, but if you try `(Get-ItemProperty IIS:\Sites\SITENAME -Name bindings).bindings.gettype()` then you it would probably say `hashtable` or `dictionary`, which is what we created with `@{ }` That's the way to store multiple key/value-pairs in an itemproperty.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this snippet

```
New-IISSiteBinding -Name 'Default Web Site' -BindingInformation "8082:*" -Protocol net.tcp
```